# Error occured when ape reading newick tree

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape

I was trying to do `ape::read.tree` on my newick files. All the `read.tree` worked well except for one of the file, which I named it 18S.

```
18S <- ape::read.tree("18S.renamed")
Error: unexpected symbol in "18S"
```

I thought it was the extra spaces/dots in the name of each tree nodes (as the rest of the files don't contain spaces/dots in the node name), but the unexpected symbol error still persist after I have removed all the symbols mentioned above.

18S file:

```
((FM205866.1_Mpus_SAG 13.81:0.000500,(((FM205868.1_Mpus_CCAP 248/4:0.000001,(FM205836.1_Mpus_CCAP 248/5:0.000001,((FM205870.1_Mpus_CCAP 248/10:0.000001,FM205867.1_Mpus_CCAP 248/11:0.000493)14:0.000001,FM205871.1_Mpus_CCAP 248/12:0.000001)6:0.000001)4:0.000001)11:0.000001,FM205869.1_Mpus_CCAP 248/9:0.000001)64:0.000493,(FM205872.1_Mpus_CCAP 248/6:0.000001,FM205873.1_Mpus_CCAP 248/15:0.000001)47:0.000001)82:0.000981)65:0.000912,(FM205875.1_Mpus_CCAP 248/3:0.000001,FM205874.1_Mpus_CCAP 248/1:0.000001)100:0.002107,((((FM205851.1_Mcon_SAG 241.80:0.001523,FM205852.1_Mcon_CCAP 211/83:0.000001)68:0.061693,(KP726221.1_Csor_KLL-G018 clone a:0.000544,((FM205859.1_Csor_CCAP 211/8K:0.000001,(FM205860.1_Csor_CCALA 260:0.000001,KP726220.1_Csor_KLL-G018 clone c:0.001474)16:0.000001)14:0.000001,FM205834.1_Csor_SAG 211-8k:0.000001)54:0.000001)70:0.046781)7:0.011137,(AB240151.1_Apyr_-:0.007009,((AB162910.1_Cvul_-:0.000001,(((((FM205855.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/82:0.000001,((((JX185298.1_Cvul_D2:0.001478,FN298917.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/109:0.000963)38:0.000491,KC517115.1_Cvul_CSA-53:0.002420)39:0.000001,((FN298920.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/112:0.000001,(FN298921.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/113:0.000001,FM205832.1_Cvul_SAG 211-11b:0.000001)13:0.000001)11:0.000001,FN298919.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/111:0.000001)59:0.000482)49:0.000489,FN298918.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/110:0.000001)7:0.000001)3:0.000001,KJ756813.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/75:0.000001)2:0.000001,(FM205854.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/81:0.000001,FN298922.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/114:0.000001)66:0.000480)1:0.000001,FM205853.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/80:0.000001)9:0.000001,KJ756823.1_Cvul_CCAP 211/21A:0.000001)40:0.000489)100:0.064516,(((AB162915.1_Cvar_KM2-ZK:0.000001,FN298923.1_Cvar_CCAP 211/84:0.000478)2:0.000001,(AB162912.1_Cvar_OK1-ZK:0.000001,(AB206549.1_Cvar_-:0.000001,(((AB162913.1_Cvar_So13-ZK:0.000001,(AB191206.1_Cvul_ShiP-7-A4:0.000001,AB191205.1_Cvul_HB2-2-1:0.000001)13:0.000001)1:0.000001,((AB162914.1_Cvar_F36-ZK:0.000001,AB162917.1_Cvar_Bnd1-ZK:0.000001)8:0.000001,AB162916.1_Cvar_Dd1-ZK:0.000001)2:0.000001)0:0.000001,AB191207.1_Cvul_takaP-3-A2:0.000705)0:0.000001)0:0.000001)0:0.000001)1:0.000001,FM205849.1_Cvar_SAG 211-6:0.000001)98:0.031452)41:0.000001)20:0.010311)9:0.010551,((FM205848.1_Dacu_SAG 41.98:0.041180,((AB162911.1_Pkes_-:0.000508,HM744739.2_Pkes_BAFC CA10:0.000001)62:0.000505,(JQ797561.1_Pkes_HY-6:0.002539,(FM205885.1_Pkes_CCAP 211/11G:0.000001,FM205846.1_Pkes_SAG 211-11g:0.000001)83:0.000001)60:0.000001)100:0.085329)100:0.070591,((AF228686.1:0.350021,LC192145.1:0.130468)61:0.075658,(KF673380.1:0.369440,((LN610701.1_Apro_CCAP 211/8D:0.001319,(FN298931.1_Apro_CCAP 211/7A:0.001165,(LN610704.1_Apro_CCAP 211/17:0.000987,FR865684.1_Apro_CCAP 211/7D:0.000765)38:0.000693)45:0.002404)100:0.522107,(KM020035.1_Mpus_SAG 8.93:0.000001,KM020034.1_Mpus_SAG 7.93:0.000001)100:0.063307)12:0.009214)10:0.009867)5:0.002021)18:0.013272)87:0.058373);
```

Other files that produced no error:

```
((MN649872.1_Mpus_CCAP2321:0.026502,(((NC_023835.1_Csor_crs4:0.000001,KJ742376.1_Cvul_1230:0.000001)100:0.016266,MK295215.1_Cvul_FACHB24:0.011133)86:0.015468,(((EU038282.1_Apyr_F5:0.002036,EU038285.1_Apro_F2:0.000001)68:0.000676,((((MK295214.1_Cvul_FACHB8:0.000001,MK295210.1_Apro_FACHB2:0.000001)13:0.000001,EU038283.1_Apyr_F9:0.000675)5:0.000001,MN128434.1_Apyr_FACHB5:0.000001)6:0.000001,MK295217.1_Apyr_FACHB415:0.000001)47:0.000001)100:0.004934,AB240145.1_Apyr_SUN:0.003627)94:0.008338)31:0.004244)35:0.005321,NC_036806.1_Mcon_-:0.020463,(((NC_015359.1_Cvar_NC64A1:0.011338,AB260903.1_Cvar_NC64A:0.000001)100:0.021374,((MK948102.1_Cvul_UTEX259:0.000001,MK948100.1_Cvul_NJ7:0.000001)75:0.000688,((D10997.1_Csor_C27:0.000001,NC_001865.1_Cvul_-:0.000001)100:0.007810,AB260909.1_Cvul_NIES227:0.000001)60:0.000001)100:0.034867)53:0.007539,((((NC_012978.1_Pkes_SAG21111g:0.025514,NC_025546.1_Dacu_SAG4198:0.032694)77:0.014592,EU038286.1_Cvul_cvq:0.036430)86:0.024282,(KY613608.1_Apro_UTEX2341:0.000001,NC_023775.1_Apro_-:0.000001)100:0.108762)50:0.014189,(NC_025541.1:0.109063,(NC_025545.1:0.231197,FJ968739.1:0.092160)42:0.032637)57:0.029130)79:0.033230)61:0.009840);
```

Do anyone have any idea what might be the other possibilities on the unexpected symbol error?

PS: I wasn't a frequent R user, just came across R when doing keep.tip, everything goes well on the rest of the trees but really have no idea on the 18S files.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You can't begin a variable name with a number in R (hence the "unexpected symbol").

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment, it's the variable you have chosen causes the error.

Comment: Thanks @heds1 and Suren !!! Have been struggling in checking all the characters inside the file lol. Learned something new :)